# Ajax change URL source onClick

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm trying to find a more effective way to change the source of XML documents that I am parsing by an html dropdown. Currently, I'm using XMLHttpRequest() but I know that ajax would be more effective. I've tried several times to incorporate ajax, but the edits to the code never seem to work. My source code is below.

```
    var baseURL = "";
    var xml, bb;

    function hl(src) {
        'use strict';
        return hljs.highlight('javascript', src).value;
    }

    function load(kind) {
        'use strict';
        var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url;
        switch (kind) {
            case 'sean': url = baseURL + 'source/sean.xml';
                break;
            case 'bruce': url = baseURL + 'source/bruce.xml';
                break;
            case 'victoria': url = baseURL + 'source/victoria.xml';
                break;
            case 'chris': url = baseURL + 'source/chris.xml';
                    break;
        }
        xhReq.open('GET', url, false);
        xhReq.send(null);
        var xml = xhReq.responseText;
        xml = xml.replace(/\t/g, '  ');
        clearAll();
        document.getElementById('xml').value = xml;
        convert();
    }

    function clearAll() {
        clearXML();
        clearJSON();
    }

    function clearXML() {
        document.getElementById('xml').value = '';
    }

    function clearJSON() {
        $('.testData').empty();
        bb = null;
    }

    function convert() {
        clearJSON();
        xml = document.getElementById('xml').value;
        bb = jsonTest(xml); <!-- External Parsing Source from XML to JSON -->
        console.log(bb.data.json());
    }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
    div class="block-section" id="convert">
        <p>
            <textarea id="xml"></textarea>
        </p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" id="ccda-menu" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span>Example</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ccda-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="load('sean')">Sean</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="load('Bruce')">Bruce</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="load('victoria')" class="ccda-load">Victoria</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="load('chris')">Chris</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button onclick="convert()" class="btn btn-default convert">Convert</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button onclick="clearAll()" class="btn btn-default clear">Clear</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

EDIT ------ This the the old code that I had that I cannot get to work with the source switch

```
window.YC = window.YC || {};
YC.get_data = function () {
    'use strict';

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'source/sean.xml',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text'
    })
        .fail(fail)
        .success(extractData);

    function extractData(summary) {
     var bb = jsonTest(summary);
     window.d = bb.data;
    }
```

Then I would return the dfd promise and address the fail.

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery? it may help manage your ajax calls better. I am unsure what you need help with in this example. Ajax is just a term used to describe fetching pages using javascript which you are already doing with `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: why not use `url = baseURL + 'source/'+kind+'.xml';` instad of the switch?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that "Bruce" != "bruce" in your switch statement. There are others.

Comment: @Filype I'm basically trying to avoid the annoying "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience" warning from Chrome

Answer (score 0):

retain the case structure you have, then use `jQuery.get()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest` and it'll work. Always works for me.

Comment: Will do, tried it but it won't fire now. Might be something I'm missing